# $\dim T^{-1}(W_1)\geq \dim V-\dim W+\dim W_1. $

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T: V\to W$ be linear transform from vector spaces $V$ to $W$. Suppose that $\dim V < \infty, \dim W < \infty$, and $W_1$ is a subspace of $W$. Prove that
> \begin{equation*}\begin{aligned} \dim T^{-1}(W_1)\geq \dim V-\dim W+\dim W_1. \end{aligned}\end{equation*}

Let $v_1,\cdots,v_r$ be a base of $T^{-1}(W_1)$, extend them to be a base of $V$ as $v_1,\cdots,v_n$. Then $Tv_1,\cdots,Tv_r\in W_1$, and $Tv_{r+1},\cdots, Tv_n$ can be show to be linearly independent. Then what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's denote $T'$ the restriction of $T$ to $T^{-1}(W_1)$. Then we have $\text{ker}(T')=\text{ker}(T)$ and $\text{im}(T')=\text{im}(T)\cap W_1$. In particular,
$$ \text{dim}(\text{im}(T'))= \text{dim}(\text{im}(T))+\text{dim}(W_1)-\text{dim}(\text{im}(T)+W_1)\geq  \text{dim}(\text{im}(T))+\text{dim}(W_1)-\text{dim}(W)\;\;\; (*)$$

But we also know that $\text{dim}(\text{im}(T))-\text{dim}(\text{im}(T'))=\text{dim}(V)-\text{dim}(T^{-1}(W_1))$, because the kernels of $T$ and $T'$ are the same, so plugging this into (*) and rearranging, we get
$$\text{dim}(T^{-1}(W_1))-\text{dim}(V) \geq \text{dim}(W_1)-\text{dim}(W) $$

which is the inequality you want to prove.